# Terraria Meteor has been "spawned" but isn't anywhere in my game/world

Tags: terraria

A couple of days ago, I killed the Eater of Worlds and afterwards expected a meteor to spawn sooner or later. I knew that as soon as I broke a Shadow Orb that I had a 50% chance of a meteor spawning and a higher percentage each day. So I thought I was simply unlucky. However after leaving Terraria up all night and getting back on to check for a meteor, I found nothing. I have no skybridge, I've checked all 7 floating islands on my world, and checked the bottom of the oceans as well as going all the way left and right on my world. I also used TerraMap just in case I was missing the meteor. TerraMap does say that I had broken the Shadow Orbs and it also says that it spawned a meteor. But when I search the map for any meteorite item, it finds nothing. I have checked multiple forums to no avail. If you know anything about this issue, please respond.

Here's an image of my world in TerraMap, where I'm searching for Meteorite. You can see that nothing is highlighted.

[image: TerraMap screenshots]

Comment: If you break more shadow orbs, does the issue persist?

Comment: I mean I can break more orbs but will that causes another meteor to spawn?

Comment: Well of course it will, but that may just need to be what you do!

Comment: I guess if that's the only thing left to do xD. I just figured if the game thinks one landed and it didn't, why would repeating the process to cause one to fall change the outcome?

Comment: No text, no evidence of a meteor in world - the obvious answer is that a meteor has not fallen. I'm not sure if the percentage chance increases - According to the wiki article, there's a 50% chance the night after breaking a heart/orb, and 2% any night following this assuming there is 1) Available space and 2) there are not too many meteor blocks in world above 0m. The best solution would be to continue breaking hearts/orbs.

Answer (score 1):

Try smashing more Shadow Orbs or making a new world. This is clearly a bug, and it may be tied to your world. Sorry for not having the best answer, but this is as far as we can get.

Answer (score -2):

Have you scanned the skies. I once had the same problem, but when I found my first sky island the meteor had completely desecrated it all accept for the chest. XD

Answer (score -2):

It probably spawned out of your world. It happened to me once as I was in the ocean meteor heads started spawning. Either that or its a glitch.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a Corruption Biome, you could check the entrances for the corruption biome. I found the meteor crash inside one of the entrances.